# std::cin input with spaces?

Tags: c++, string, user-input, space, cin

```
#include <string>

std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

The user wants to enter "Hello World". But `cin` fails at the space between the two words. How can I make `cin` take in the whole of `Hello World`?

I'm actually doing this with structs and `cin.getline` doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
struct cd
{
    std::string CDTitle[50];
    std::string Artist[50];
    int number_of_songs[50];
};

std::cin.getline(library.number_of_songs[libNumber], 250);
```

This yields an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your questions to ask new questions like that.  The reason is that people have already given answers to your original question and now those answers seem out of context.  If your original question has already been answered just start a new question to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's apparent after a little examination, but could you please add a declaration for the variable `library` so that it's clear that it is of the type `cd`

Comment: there's good stuff here, no need to delete

Comment: In your update, you're trying to `getline` into an `int`.  Of course that fails.

Comment: You should probably know this by now (considering the age of this question) but you're really using structures and array wrong. You should have a structure with a *single* `CDTitle`, a *single* `Artist` and a *single* `number_of_songs`. Then have an array (or better yet a `std::vector`) of the structure.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have to use [`cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
char input[100];
cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));
```

Comment: @Kevin Meh, it happens.  C++ isn't exactly as intuitive as we would like it to be.

Comment: Ew; why use `char`-buffers? It's 2011.

Comment: And why not use `cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));`?  Also, shouldn't you check the return status?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler At the time this was written, this was the answer I had for the question that was originally asked (look at the first comment for the actual question and you will see that the context had changed due to an edit by the OP).  Either way, if you feel the answer is that terrible, downvote it.  I acknowledge that this may not be the "best" solution but it's a solution no less. Instead of asking why I didn't use something, you could tell us all why we should do it your way.

Comment: Your answer is not terrible and doesn't need downvoting. I do think two small changes would improve it. Change 1 would use `sizeof(input)` in place of 100 in the call to `cin.getline()`; that would mean you can change the size of the input buffer and only need to change one line instead of two lines. Change 2 would be to test the return from `cin.getline()` by using, for example, `if (!cin.getline(input, sizeof(input))) { ...handle EOF or error... }` or something similar, to remind the OP that input operations, in particular, are vulnerable to unexpected behaviour. Other answers need this too.

Answer (score 300):

It doesn't "fail"; it just stops reading. It sees a lexical token as a "string".

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string name, title;
   
   std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, name);
   
   std::cout << "Enter your favourite movie: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, title);
   
   std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;
}
```

Note that this is *not* the same as `std::istream::getline`, which works with C-style `char` buffers rather than `std::string`s.

**Update**

Your edited question bears little resemblance to the original.

You were trying to `getline` into an `int`, not a string or character buffer. The formatting operations of streams only work with `operator<<` and `operator>>`. Either use one of them (and tweak accordingly for multi-word input), or use `getline` and lexically convert to `int` after-the-fact.

Comment: I like this answer much better than the accepted one, because I don't need to specify a character length.

Comment: @TheWanderer Indeed, that's a significant benefit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, can you please help? This gives me an extra newline for no reason while printing my output.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I think `getline` may include the terminating newline in the string it returns.  If so, it's up to you to delete it.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly what's been suggested and it doesn't work for me.
It prints "Enter your name: Enter your favorite movie" ...

Comment: Use ws (whitespace) in getline() like getline(cin>>ws, name);
If numeric input is before the string then due to whitespace the first string input will be ignored. Therefore use ws like getline(cin>>ws, name);  

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    main(){
     int id=0; 
     string name, address;
 
     cout <<"Id? "; cin>>id;
 
     cout <<"Name? ";
     getline(cin>>ws, name);
 
     cout <<"Address? ";
     getline(cin>>ws, address);
 
    cout <<"\nName: " <<name <<"\nAddress: " <<address;
    }

Comment: @PedroSilveira maybe it skips `getline`, try `cin.ignore();` before `getline`, got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077260/1496974)

Answer (score 79):

The Standard Library provides an input function called `ws`, which consumes whitespace from an input stream.  You can use it like this:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s);
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. I can combine this with the std::cin>> on above.

Comment: Best answer so far. When using `std::getline(std::cin, s)` I would get a very messy and I would say, interrupted input when waiting for inputs in a `while`/`for` loop. This option resolved my issue!

Comment: Include sstream: #include <sstream>

Answer (score 36):

Use :

```
getline(cin, input);
```

the function can be found in

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that actually worked for me. The rest of the answers say to use cin.getline() but that just gave me an error saying the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @blembo: Really? Because my answer, posted more than three years before this one, says the exact same thing (as opposed to what you claim it says).

Comment: @blembo: And if `cin.getline` doesn't exist on your system, you have done something very wrong. Most likely you were passing the wrong arguments. Best not to blame others for your mistakes...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand how this answer can be viewed as a subset of your answer (content-wise). The problem mentioned in that comment might have been a consequence of the difference in presentation and the order of answers in this thread (wrt. the tick & votes). If a speed reader begins unsatisfied with the C-style getline, followed by a much longer answer of yours (though useful for focused readers), followed by another way of using getline, the reader may finally conclude that this answer is the better of them, which basically resembles yours, but in a concise manner.

Answer (score 15):

You want to use the .getline function in cin.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  char name[256], title[256];

  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin.getline (name,256);

  cout << "Enter your favourite movie: ";
  cin.getline (title,256);

  cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;

  return 0;
}
```

Took the example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/). Check it out for more info and examples.

Comment: In fact, you rarely want to use member-`getline`. It's outmoded. Use free `getline` instead, which can be used with `std::string`. [BTW, cplusplus.com is _not_ a recommended resource]

Comment: Then what should I use? On the rare occasion I am doing c++ and need a reference, cplusplus.com is always the first google result for me.

Comment: @Tomalak Why is cplusplus.com not recommended? I use it all the time :P

Comment: @KevinDuke: The tutorials can be misleading and inaccurate, and the reference contains a multitude of errors. [These](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) are good resources.

Comment: Dead link? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @NickSweeting: Yeah; use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: For documentation links, cppreference.com is an effective replacement for cplusplus.com (both are non-official paraphrases)

Answer (score 6):

**How do I read a string from input?**

You can read a single, whitespace terminated word with `std::cin` like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a word:\n";

    string s;
    cin>>s;

    cout << "You entered " << s << '\n';
}
```

Note that there is no explicit memory management and no fixed-sized buffer that you could possibly overflow.
If you really need a whole line (and not just a single word) you can do this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a line:\n";

    string s;
    getline(cin,s);

    cout << "You entered " << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**THE C WAY**

You can use `gets` function found in cstdio(stdio.h in c):

```
#include<cstdio>
int main(){

char name[256];
gets(name); // for input
puts(name);// for printing 
}
```

**THE C++ WAY**

`gets` is removed in c++11.

[Recommended]:You can use [getline(cin,name)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) which is in `string.h`
or [cin.getline(name,256)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) which is in `iostream` itself.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char name1[256];
string name2;
cin.getline(name1,256); // for input
getline(cin,name2); // for input
cout<<name1<<"\n"<<name2;// for printing
}
```

Comment: Very bad advice, `gets` is impossible to use safely. It's even been removed completely in C11.

Answer (score 2):

I rather use the following method to get the input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string name;

    cout << "Hello, Input your name please: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    return 0;
}
```

It's actually super easy to use rather than defining the total length of array for a string which contains a space character.