# Why do spaces get lost in pipes in Linux?

Tags: c++, pipe

I have an issue with pipes in Linux. Looks like space characters are lost after piping. Running the following `C++` code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char s[] = "ab cd", c;
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(int i = 0; i<n && (cin >> c); i++)
        if(s[i] != c){
            printf("wrong at %d : '%c' != '%c' \n", i, s[i], c);
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

from

```
echo "ab cd" | ./checker
```

shell command gives

```
wrong at 2 : ' ' != 'c'
```

Is it normal behavior? How to avoid losing characters in pipes?

Comment: Because CIN consumes whitespace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462021/issue-with-cin-when-spaces-are-inputted-using-string-class

Comment: @kfsone - `cin` doesn't consume whitespace; stream extractors (`operator>>`) do, regardless of what stream the data is coming from.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yep, bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the pipe, the problem is `cin >> c` which skips over whitespace.

It would work if you do `cin >> noskipws >> c`

or something like this:

```
std::string q;
getline(cin, q);

for(i = 0; i < n && i < q.size(); i++)
{
  if (q[i] != s[i]) 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour when using `cin` and has nothing to do with pipes.

You may want to tell the stream not to ignore white spaces:

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws;
```

Then proceed as you're already doing.

Comment: That is the default behavior when using stream extractors (`operator>>`), regardless of what stream the extractor is applied to. In addition to using `std::noskipws`, you can read individual characters without skipping whitespace with `basic_istream::get()`. `operator>>` is a **formatted** stream operation; `get` is unformatted.