# string with spaces in an array

Tags: c++

I have an array of strings called peliculas:

```
        string peliculas[10][4];
```

and I  have a tamanopeli that is a number. This number tells me in which position the new pelicula will be added.  But the problem is that I need the user to be able to write a data with space.  But if the user intends to write "fast and fourious", then the program save it as

```
peliculas[tamanopeli][0]= fast
peliculas[tamanopeli][1]= and
peliculas[tamanopeli][2]= fourius
```

and I need

```
peliculas[tamanopeli][0] = fast and fourius
```

because "fast and fourius" is only 1 string

```
                 cout<<"wtite the name of the movie: ";
                 cin>>peliculas[tamanopeli][0];

                 cout<<"\nwrite the gender: ";
                 cin>>peliculas[tamanopeli][1];

                 cout<<"\nwrite first date: ";
                 cin>>peliculas[tamanopeli][2];

                 cout<<"\n write last date: ";
                 cin>>peliculas[tamanopeli][3];
```

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5838723/336802

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::getline`:

```
getline( cin, peliculas[tamanopeli][0] );
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think what you needed is just the cin.getline(), which can read a string with the space.
It's can get a whole line of string~

Answer (score 0):

You are using cin to collect data. cin stops reading at the first whitespace. Instead use getline()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string input;
getline(cin, input);

cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not `cin` that stops at the first whitespace, it's its `operator<<` that does. You are using `cin` in `getline`, too, after all.

Comment: True. But getline will still go back and make sure nothing is left behind

Comment: I didn't question your proposed solution, but your answer says: _cin stops reading at the first whitespace_. That's nonsense.