# getting error on run time when i give space between words

Tags: c++

I am storing words on run time in array but when i give space between words the program don't ask for second input it give me an output directly without taking second input here is my coding .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
char a[50];
char b[50];
cout<<"please tell us what is your language\t";
cin>>a;
cout<<"please tell us what is your language\t";
cin>>b;
cout<<a<<b;
getch();
}
```

[image: here is my output]

Comment: Maybe you should use `std::getline` instead of the `>>` extraction operator, if you want to read lines and not white-space separated words.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

Comment: You shouldn't use `cin>>a;` if `a` is an array, because it's unsafe (if you don't provide a width via `cin >> setw(49)`). If anyone uses a word longer than 50 characters, you'll get buffer overflows, access violations and all kinds of undefined behaviour. Better use a `std::string`.

Comment: but i have declare the using keyword above why do i need std and scope resolution operator

Comment: You don't, that's just the way I type it to make clear it's part of the Standard library ;)

Comment: ok sir let me try if you give me a little more idea i will be thank full to you

Comment: std::string c; i have try like that is it right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<conio.h>    // better don't use this, it's not portable
#include <string>

//using namespace std; // moving this inside the function
int main(){
    using namespace std;  // a bit more appropriate here

    string a;
    string b;

    cout<<"please tell us what is your language\t";
    getline(cin, a);  // `a` will automatically grow to fit the input
    cout<<"please tell us what is your language\t";
    getline(cin, b);
    cout<<a<<b;

    //getch();            // not portable, from conio.h
    // alternative to getch:
    cin.ignore();
}
```

A reference for [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (with an example at the bottom) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).