# How to store multiple inputs into a list C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming and am trying to create a program that asks the user questions. For example,

```
std::string siblings;
std::cout << "How many siblings do you have?";  //Let's say the user inputs 2
std::cin >> siblings;

for (int x=0;x<n;x++){
    std::string current;
    std::string sibling_info;
    std::cout << "What is the name + age of sibling #" << (x+1) << ": ";
    std::cin >> current;                    
    sibling_info.emplace_back(current);
```

I want the user to input "John 13" with a space in between, but whenever I put a space the program does not run the way I want it to and doesn't ask the user twice.

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, current);` but you still have to parse the name from the number somewhere - you don't show us that code though

Comment: The same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input from cin is white space delineated which includes spaces. `std::cin >> current` stores only the first word which was typed. In order to get two words you'd have to call cin twice, or switch to a different way of getting user input.

```
std::string current;
std::string age;
std::string sibling_info;
std::cout << "What is the name + age of sibling #" << (x+1) << ": ";
std::cin >> current; //you were missing a semicolon :p
std::cin >> age;    //added
current += " " + age;      //added       
sibling_info.emplace_back(current);
```

or using getline (you need to `#include<string>`)

```
std::string current;
std::string sibling_info;
std::cout << "What is the name + age of sibling #" << (x+1) << ": ";
current = getline(cin,current); //changed                      
sibling_info.emplace_back(current);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
std::string current[2];
...
std::cin >> current[0] >> current[1];
sibling_info.emplace_back(current[0]+" "+current[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `emplace_back()` can be used for `vector`, but not for `string`. So you need to change

```
std::string sibling_info;
```

to

```
std::vector<std::string> sibling_info;
```

Then you can call:

```
sibling_info.emplace_back(current);
```

At the same time, it will enable you to input any number of multiple inputs.

Check out [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) for more info.