# Unexpected cin behavior

Tags: c++, string

I am writing a function `int count_words(string str)` that returns a count of all of the words in the string.

The issue is that regardless of the input, the result is 1. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int count_words(string str)
{
    int i,j;
    j = 1;
    int l = str.length();
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        string c = str.substr(i,1);
        if(c == " ")
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The total word in the string: " << j << endl;
    return j;
}


int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin >> str;
    int result = count_words(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a question which arrises from a fundamental *conceptual* mistake, especially when all the necessary information to recognize the problem has been included.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`cin.getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) if your string contains spaces, as using the `>>` operator with `cin` only reads up to the next whitespace

Comment: Nice simple answer that explains the reason _why_ to use getline.

Comment: awesome, I also learn something. (its very rare to use console input)

Answer (score 3):

See [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces)

Consider iterating over the string:

```
auto cstyle= str.c_str();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
{
  if (cstyle[i]==' ')//assumes words are delimited by a single space
  {
    j++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use: `cin.getline`, for example:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    unsigned size=10;
    char*chr=new char[size];
    cin.getline(chr,size);
    string str(chr);
    //cin >> str;
    int result = count_words(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the downvote might be related to the fact that unlike the others who proposed this solution, you haven't given any explanation of why your method will work when the poster's attempt failed - there's little to be *learned* from your answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, it can be.