# array not store/print second part of name

Tags: c++

I am want to enter name in array and then willing to print it on screen. Code is given below

```
char name[20];          
cout << "Please enter name: ";
cin >> name;          
cout << name << endl;
```

Then after compilation I entered name

```
Ali Waqas
```

After that `Ali` is printed on screen but `Waqas` doesn’t.
I have replace my cout statement with this loop

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
   cout << name[i];
}
```

Again `Ali` is printed but after that garbage is printing rather `Waqas`

Comment: [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: So with `cin` and `cout`, obviously C++ code. You know C != C++, right? You should also be using `std::string` instead of C strings.

Comment: @crashmstr what about my question ?

Comment: @muhammadkhan _what about my question ?_ Check the 1st comment! Didn't need to be restated.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
getline()
```

to get desired results. You will not get correct output with current code because operator << ignores the white spaces. You have to use this type of code

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

For the further more details you must go through this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because operator<< skips white space. You could use `getline()` to get the desired effect.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but for now i want to do it wit char array, rather string.

Comment: @muhammadkhan Why?? Why would you use a cumbersome and unsafe array instead of the standard `std::string` type?

Comment: @Angew i want to do experiment, as i am beginner of c/c++

Comment: @muhammadkhan Even more reason to learn & get familiar with the lanuage using everyday tools (`std::string`), before you delve down to the complex specialised ones (manual management of a nul-terminated `char` string).