# Reading two strings as one?

Tags: c++, string

I am working on making a program for making lists but having trouble adding anything that is more than one word. (i.e. pop rocks, or toilet paper)

```
cout<<"What would you like to add?"<<endl;
    string NewItem;
    cin>>NewItem;
```

Right now I'm using cin but I saw something about getline() though nothing about if it would help me. When I tried it all I got was a runtime error so I'm not really sure what went wrong.

```
getline(cin, NewItem);
```

That is what I replaced the cin with when I tried it.
Run time error didn't look for user input it just paused for a second.

Comment: Yes, `getline()` will certainly help you. Which runtime error message did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces

Comment: It just ignored it completely. Like there was nothing there.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, all we can do is guess. I guess that you are mixing the use of `cin >>` and `getline()`, (specifically using `cin >>` in some code before that which you have shown), which almost always doesn't do what you expect. I suggest changing all use of `cin >>` to `getline()` which will behave much more intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix `getline` and `cin >>` (or, if use, use with care, as `cin` leaves whitespaces in the buffer that may end up "eaten" by `getline`, so you must ignore them). Use only `getline`, like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "What would you like to add?" << endl;
    string NewItem;
    getline(cin, NewItem);

    std::cout << "You added: " << NewItem << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin`  extract data to string variable until it see delimiter character in stream. New line and  space are delimiters to this function. That is the reason you can't read the string  like "  pop rocks" completely. It will read up to first space and stop reading from stream.

Comment: the `>>` operator on `cin` will eat newline and space. `get()` would be better. `getline` likely even better.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how to get rid of the space as a delimitter.

Comment: AndyG - Trouble comes in the actual application of the two. I don't know if I have the syntax wrong or what but I'm getting nothing from it.