# C++ if/else if statement not working correctly

Tags: c++

I am trying to code a little game-like adventure program, and I need if else statements in it for it to work correctly. However, whenever I run this if else statement, it does not output what I want.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        cout << endl << "What will you do?: ";
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "Nothing" || input == "nothing")
            {
                cout << "Why would you do nothing?" << endl;
            }
            else if (input == "Look North" || input == "Look north" || input == "look North" || input == "look north")
            {
                cout << "You look north. There is nothing north." << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

What I expect it to output would be this:

```
What will you do?: nothing
Why would you do nothing?

What will you do?: look north
You look north. There is nothing north.

What will you do?:
```

But instead of getting that when I put those as an input, I get this:

```
What will you do?: nothing
Why would you do nothing?

What will you do?: look north

What will you do?:
What will you do?:
```

I would like some help on resolving this issue, as I cannot find an answer to why this would be happening.

Comment: Debugging tip: Output the thing you've just input to verify that it is what you think it is.

Comment: Or run through a debugger and examine the input variables.  Not much different but I find it a bit cleaner.

Comment: Game design tip: as soon as you will have about 10 locations linked to each others, you will start to hate everything. Think about making locations and links to other locations data-driven

Comment: Please *transform* your strings into all lowercase or all uppercase before comparing.  This reduces the need to compare for "nOrth", "NoRtH", "North", "north" and all other combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cin >> input;
```

does not read whitespaces. You need to use `std::getline`.

```
getline(cin, input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you input "Look north"
using 
cin>>input;
 only "Look" is saved into the input variable ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with`cin` statement as it does not handle white spaces, try what is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces). Also, you will find helpfull the `tolower()` function, to normalize your inputs.