# Pulling individual words from manual input of unknown length

Tags: c++, vector, user-input

Re-post as I didn't include enough info in the last one.

I tried my best google fu and can't seem to find the right answer (doesn't mean it's not a stupid mistake, as I'm still new)

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> clauses;
    string test;

    cout << "Please enter your choice or choices\n\ ";

    while (cin >> test) {
        clauses.push_back(test);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how many options they will enter so I'm throwing them in a vector.

Currently when it runs it won't take any user input and just let the person keep typing even when hitting enter. c

Thanks in advance. Paul

Comment: That might have something to do with formatted extraction e.g. `operator>>` ignoring and skipping over the whitespaces. Use `std::getline`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ cin input with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: You might boil this question down to: *"How to read a line?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for what you want to do :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> clauses;
    std::string test;

    std::cout << "Please enter your choice or choices\n";

    do
    {
        getline(std::cin, test);
        if(!test.empty())
            clauses.push_back(test);

    }while (!test.empty());

    return 0;
}
```

The getline function will read any text on the keyboard and push it in your vector until the user only use the Enter key, which will end the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much Isuka. For anybody who finds this later through Google the code Isuka published works perfectly.