# Error in Quiz Function Based Off String Length

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm having some minor trouble with this basic C++ quiz program. In the main function, I have the user enter his/her name and I pass this string to the next function, take_quiz. However, I've noticed that if I include a name with a space in it (like a first and last name), an error occurs. For some reason, the amount of letters in the second word produces the same amount of displays of, "Please enter a valid answer (a, b, c, d)." I thought this was strange because that prompt can only occur when the inline function valCheck is used which is after the first cin of a variable in take_quiz. I need some help identifying the issue and correcting it. Thanks!

```
inline char valCheck(char& input)
    {
         tolower(input);
         while(input < 97 || input > 100)
         {    
             cout << "Please enter a valid answer (a, b, c, d):" << endl;
             cin  >> input;
         }
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
         string name;

         cout << "This program will quiz your knowledge of C++. Please enter your name:" << endl;
         cin  >> name;
         cout << "Hello " << name << "! IT'S QUIZ TIME!!!" << endl;
         take_quiz(name);

         system("PAUSE");
         return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    void take_quiz(string name2)
    {    
         char quiz_results[10];
         system("PAUSE");
         cout << "\nThe quiz will now begin.\nThis quiz covers topics such as data types, arrays, pointers, etc." << endl
              << "To answer the multiple choice questions,\nsimply input a, b, c, or d according to the given options." << endl
              << "The test will continue regardless if you enter a question wrong or right." << endl
              << "Good luck " << name2 << "!" << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
         cout << "\n1. What preprocessor command must one include to use the cout and cin function?" << endl
              << "\na.  #include <iomanip>" << endl
              << "b.    #include <iostream>" << endl
              << "c.    #include <cmath>" << endl
              << "d.    using namespace std;" << endl;
         cin >> quiz_results[0];
         valCheck(quiz_results[0]);
```

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces) on how to use `cin` to get a text stream containing spaces.

Comment: `valCheck()` doesn't return anything - according to signature it needs to return a `char` value. You want to use `std::getline(std::cin, str);` instead of `cin` if your string contains newlines.

Comment: Hey Constantin the std::getline(std::cin, str) function worked great! However I don't think I needed to have valCheck return anything because it's accepting a reference and it is changing input. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @CZou48 Yes, correct - but then you should change the signature to: `inline void valCheck(char& input)` instead of `inline char valCheck(char& input)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `valCheck()` doesn't return anything - according to signature it needs to return a char value. You want to use [std::getline(std::cin, str);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead of `std::cin` if your string contains newlines. `std::cin` will by default skip whitespaces. Also you're invoking `take_quiz()` without a prototype function before, so you need to move it above `main()` or specify the function signature at least above.

The complete program should look like this (you just need to add a check if `quiz_results[0]` is equal to 'b').

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

inline char valCheck(char& input){
  tolower(input);
  while (input < 97 || input > 100){
    cout << "Please enter a valid answer (a, b, c, d):" << endl;
    cin >> input;
  }
  return input;
}
void take_quiz(string name2)
{
  char quiz_results[10];
  system("PAUSE");
  cout << "\nThe quiz will now begin.\nThis quiz covers topics such as data types, arrays, pointers, etc." << endl
    << "To answer the multiple choice questions,\nsimply input a, b, c, or d according to the given options." << endl
    << "The test will continue regardless if you enter a question wrong or right." << endl
    << "Good luck " << name2 << "!" << endl;
  system("PAUSE");
  cout << "\n1. What preprocessor command must one include to use the cout and cin function?" << endl
    << "\na.  #include <iomanip>" << endl
    << "b.  #include <iostream>" << endl
    << "c.  #include <cmath>" << endl
    << "d.  using namespace std;" << endl;
  cin >> quiz_results[0];
  valCheck(quiz_results[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  string name;
  cout << "This program will quiz your knowledge of C++. Please enter your name:" << endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, name);
  cout << "Hello " << name << "! IT'S QUIZ TIME!!!" << endl;
  take_quiz(name);
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed how to get string input from User

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
         char name[100];
         cout << "This program will quiz your knowledge of C++. Please enter  your name:" << endl;
         cin.getline(name,sizeof(name));
         //cin  >> name;
         cout << "Hello " << name << "! IT'S QUIZ TIME!!!" << endl;
         take_quiz(name);

         system("PAUSE");
         return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Why using a stack allocated char array of 100 bytes, instead of the much nicer & safer [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class?