# cin issue with space

Tags: c++, string, cin

So I was trying to read something from cin and spaces cut them,
For example, if I got

```
AA 3 4 5
111 222 33
```

from cin, I want to store them in a string array.
My code so far is

```
string temp;
int x = 0;
string array[256];
while(!cin.eof())
{
    cin >> temp;
    array[x] = temp;
    x += 1;
}
```

but then the program crashed.
Then I added cout to tried figure out what is in temp and it shows:

```
AA345
```

So how can I store the input into an array with spaces cutting them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ cin input with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/c-cin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv, that is actually the exact opposite of suggested duplicate.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv eh no, I mean I want to store every word in an array,with spaces cutting them. So in the example, I want to store AA in array[0], and store 3 in array[1], 4 in array[2] etc.

Comment: You need to provide the whole code, and indicate exactly where it crashed. There is nothing in the provided  code which would cause an aplication to crash, unless you have more than 256 tokens, which is unlikely.

Comment: @SergeyA , I'd love to but I am afraid I may violate some rules...

Comment: @GzAndy, than you might well delete your posting. I know a couple of users here do have working crystal balls, but they are not active in this thread, and I do not have one - so nobody would be able to help you.

Comment: @SergeyA, Let's forget about the crashes cause I just figured out that it is not this part of code. So my concern now is how to divide the cin, ie. if I add cout<<temp right after cin>>temp, it shouldn't shows :"AAA 3 4 5" instead of "AAA345"

Comment: @GzAndy, you still need to provide the code. I have no idea how you are printing your stuff.

Comment: Do you have more than 256 inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility to treat an input from `cin` with an arbitrary number of whitespaces between the entries, and to store the data in a vector by using the boost library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
int main() {
  std::string temp;
  std::vector<std::string> entries;
  while(std::getline(std::cin,temp)) {  
      boost::split(entries, temp, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);
      std::cout << "number of entries: " << entries.size() << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i) 
        std::cout << "entry number " << i <<" is "<< entries[i] << std::endl;                  
    }  
  return 0;
}
```

**edit**

The same result could be obtained without using the awesome boost library, e.g., in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
  std::string temp;
  std::vector<std::string> entries;
  while(std::getline(std::cin,temp)) {    
      std::istringstream iss(temp);
      while(!iss.eof()){ 
        iss >> temp;
        entries.push_back(temp);    
      }
      std::cout << "number of entries: " << entries.size() << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i)  
        std::cout<< "entry number " << i <<" is "<< entries[i] << std::endl;
      entries.erase(entries.begin(),entries.end()); 
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**example**

Input:

```
AA 12  6789     K7
```

Output:

```
number of entries: 4
entry number 0 is AA
entry number 1 is 12
entry number 2 is 6789
entry number 3 is K7
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any other ways to do this without including boost?

Comment: Certainly there are. I just like using boost ;-)

Comment: boosting is not allowed in this case:( can you give another solution plz?