# C++ Displaying a string (with blank spaces) into a two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I know that there are already several questions answered about this topic but none of them could help me solve my problem. Please, have in mind that I have just started learning C++ Programming.

I am creating a program that reads a text and then displays it in N rows x M columns (entered by the user). So, if the user writes  *HarryPotter*  and wants it to be displayed in a 3 x 4 array it should look something like this:

```
H a r r
y P o t
t e r
```

I have already manage to do so with this code:

```
cout << "Number of rows: ";
cin >> nr;
cout << "Number of columns: ";
cin >> nc;
cout << "Type in text: ";
cin >> text;

char letters[100][100];

for (int row = 0; row < nr; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < nc; col++)
    {
        letters[row][col]= text [i];
        i++;
    }   
}

cout << "Print array: " << endl;
for (int row = 0; row < nr; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < nc; col++)
        {
            cout << letters[row][col];
        }

    cout << "\n";
    }
```

And it works fine until the user writes more than one word. For example instead of  *HarryPotter* he writes *Harry Potter* (I think that the blank spaces between the words is what creates the problem). Do you know why this happens and how can I solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the variable text defined? And what to do iif the total elements of the two dimensional array is greater than the number of characters in text?

Comment: you should also add null terminated to to the end of the input text

Comment: I suspect [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will soon be in your future.

Comment: you should use `cin.getline()` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-in-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `operator >>` stops entering a string when a white space character is encountered in the stream. You should use standard function `std::getline` instead.

Take into account that to display a string there is no need to define an array. The task can be done without using an array.

Here is a  demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Number of rows (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int rows;
        if ( not ( std::cin >> rows ) or ( rows == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << "Number of columns (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int cols;
        if ( not ( std::cin >> cols ) or ( cols == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

        std::cout << "Type in text: (Enter - exit): ";

        std::string text;
        std::getline( std::cin, text );
        if ( text.empty() ) break;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::string::size_type n = text.size();

        n = std::min<std::string::size_type>( n, cols * rows );

        for ( std::string:: size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << text[i];

            std::cout << ( ( i + 1 ) % cols == 0 ? '\n' : ' ' );
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Number of rows (0 - exit): 3
Number of columns (0 - exit): 4
Type in text: (Enter - exit): HarryPotter

H a r r
y P o t
t e r

Number of rows (0 - exit): 2
Number of columns (0 - exit): 6
Type in text: (Enter - exit): HarryPotter

H a r r y P
o t t e r 

Number of rows (0 - exit): 6
Number of columns (0 - exit): 2
Type in text: (Enter - exit): HarryPotter

H a
r r
y P
o t
t e
r 

Number of rows (0 - exit): 4
Number of columns (0 - exit): 4
Type in text: (Enter - exit): Antonella Masini 

A n t o
n e l l
a   M a
s i n i

Number of rows (0 - exit): 0
```

You may substitute this statement

```
if ( not ( std::cin >> rows ) or ( rows == 0 ) ) break;
```

for this statement

```
if ( !( std::cin >> rows ) || ( rows == 0 ) ) break;
```

if the compiler does not compile the first statement. If you use MS VC++ then in the properties of the project you should switch off using of the language extensions (C++, language), and the statement will be compiled.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response but when I put it in my code it says that it doesn't identify the variable not...

Comment: @AntonellaMasini What compiler do you use?

Comment: @AntonellaMasini In any case you can just write if ( !( std::cin >> rows ) || ( rows == 0 ) ) break;

Comment: Just one more question (if you don't mind) what is this for? cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

And do you think that over this code I could build some lines that will allow the user to replace a word in the text they have previously typed?

Comment: And what does this mean? cout << ((i + 1) % cols == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');     sorry for so many questions!

Comment: @AntonellaMasini This is so-called ternary operator. It is equivalent to if(  n + 1 ) % cols == 0 ) std::cout << '\n'; else std::cout << ' ';

Answer (score 1):

`cin` will consider the space between `Harry` and `Potter` as a delimiter and only save `Harry` in `text`.

With `cin.getline`, the entire line is read until the `Enter` key is pressed. Therefore, with `cin.getline(text, sizeof(text))`, `Harry Potter` will be saved in `text`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but do I just need to replace my "cin >> text;" with "cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));" ? Because I tried that and it doesn't let me run the program because it says that "no instance of overloaded function... matches the argument list"...

Comment: You can use `getline(cin , string)` as well.

Comment: cin.getline(czTmp, row * col) that you have used should be fine. czTmp should ideally be allocated (row*col) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dynamic array of characters so it is sized at run-time as the user input of rows and columns:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row, col;

    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Col: ";
    cin >> col;

    char** cText = new char*[row];
    for(int i(0); i < row; i++)
        cText[i] = new char[col];

    cin.sync(); // clearing the input buffer
    cout << "Text: ";

    char czTmp[100];
    cin.getline(czTmp, row * col); // getting user input text which fits to our 2d array of chars

    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cText[i][j] = czTmp[k]; // inputting our array
            k++;
        }
    }

    cText[row - 1][col - 1] = '\0'; // adding a null-terminator because it is not added automatically

    // printing our array
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < col; j++)
            cout << cText[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    // don't forget to free memory created by new

    for(int i(0); i < row; i++)
        delete[] cText[i];
    delete[] cText;
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when I used your code it crashed after I entered the number of columns, do you know why this is?