# Using RegEx to filter wrong Input?

Tags: c++, regex

Look at this example:

```
string str = "January 19934";
```

The Outcome should be

```
Jan 1993
```

I think I have created the right RegEx `([A-z]{3}).*([\d]{4})` to use in this case but I do not know what I should do now?

How can I extract what I am looking for, using RegEx? Is there a way like receiving 2 variables, the first one being the result of the first RegEx bracket: `([A-z]{3})` and the second result being 2nd bracket:`[[\d]{4}]`?

Comment: Show your actual [MCVE] please. Include regex usage. And lookup "capturing groups".

Comment: I cannot edit just 1 character, but i guess the  19934 is a typo.

Comment: On a side note, where is the input coming from? If it's user-entered, it could be either 1993 or 1994 (or maybe 1934), humans are unpredictable.

Comment: It only takes about five lines of code to write a parser that handles this directly. There's no need for regular expressions here.

Comment: @PeteBecker I guess you are right, I wanted to know a solution using RegEx though

Comment: @KOB actually "19934" was correct because "1994" would've been to easy to use RegEx on and users sometimes fail Input and it is not bad to include possibility in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex contains a common typo: [`[A-z]` matches more than just ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970). Also, the `.*` will grab all the string up to its end, and backtracking will force `\d{4}` match the *last* 4 digits. You need to use *lazy* quantifier with the dot, `*?`.

Then, use `regex_search` and concat the 2 group values:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex r("([A-Za-z]{3}).*?([0-9]{4})");
    string s("January 19934");
    smatch match;
    std::stringstream res("");
    if (regex_search(s, match, r)) {
        res << match.str(1) << " " << match.str(2);
    }
    cout << res.str();  // => Jan 1993
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/UdzfZI)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `([A-Za-z]{3})`  - Group 1: three ASCII letters
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break symbols as few as possible
- `([0-9]{4})` - Group 2: 4 digits

Comment: The output isn't "Jan 9934"?

Comment: @KOB: *The Outcome should be `Jan 1993`*

Comment: Instead of nongready maybe it is better to use `\D*` instead of `.*?`

Comment: @Slava: It depends on what kind of strings are expected. I suggested the minimal fix. If there are other digits, say, 1 or 2 or 3 digit chunks before the year, using `\D*` will prevent the match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your example is working, do you know why it is not working anymore when I use Userinput string as `s` ? No Output is being shown even though the String should be the same as "January 19934"

Comment: Are you sure it is `std::string`? Check the [`regex_search` signatures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) and check what type of data you pass to `regex_search`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i am using `std::string s;` `cin >> s;` instead of `string s("January 19934");` , I have tried debugging to see what exactly is passed to regex_search with Watches in CodeBlocks, couldnt find anything though

Comment: Aha, that is unrelated to the current question and the answer is [already provided here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-in-input-with-spaces).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh god I am so stupid, forgot that cin cuts off whitespaces with string, need to use getline, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This could work.

```
([A-Za-z]{3})([a-z ])+([\d]{4})
```

Note the space after a-z is important to catch space.

Comment: Why the quantified group in middle? How about just `([A-Za-z]{3})[a-z ]+([\d]{4})`

Comment: You are right @bobblebubble I might have some idea to make it group yesterday but today I even can not remember my reasoning so its sign - that was bad idea :)