# The program seems to ignore the second input line

Tags: c++

So I have been studying programming from the book PPP by Bjarne Stroustrup and there is the following assignment:

19. Write a program where you first enter a set of name·and·value pairs,
    such as Joe 17 and Barbara 22. For each pair, add the name to a vector
    called names and the number to a vector called scores (in corresponding
    positions, so that if names[7]=="Joe" then scores[7]==18). Terminate
    input by the line No more ("more" will make the attempt to read another
    integer fail ). Check that each name is unique and terminate with an error
    message if a name is entered twice. Write out all the (name,score) pairs,
    one per line.
20. Modify the program from exercise 19 so that when you enter a name,
    the program will output the corresponding score or "name not found".
21. Modify the program from exercise 19 so that when you enter an integer,
    the program will Output all the names with that score or "score not found".
    So this is the code I wrote:

    ```
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        vector <string> names;
        string name;
        vector <int> scores;
        int score;
        string finish = "no more";
        cout << "Please write a player's name and the player's score: \n";
        while (name != "|") {
            cin >> name;
            cin >> score;
            names.push_back(name);
            scores.push_back(score);
            cin.ignore();
        }       
        for (size_t j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) {
        for (size_t p = 0; p < scores.size(); p++) {
            if (names[j] == names[p] && j != p) {
                cout << "Error! You have reiterated the name: " << names[j] << "\n";
                system("pause");
                return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Please insert a name to see it's score:\n";
        string s = " ";
        cin >> s;
            for (size_t d = 0; d < scores.size(); d++) {
                if (s == names[d]) { 
                    cout << names[d] << "'s score is: " << scores[d] << "\n";
                }
        }
        system("pause");
    }
    ```

Now my problem is quite simple I believe. In the second **cin (cin >> s)** the compiler simply seems to skip this line and terminates the program instead of letting me write an input. I read online that it is because that you can't use **cin** twice so when I added the line `cin.ignore()`, hoping that the problem will be solved, it did not help solve the problem. Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: It's not the compiler ignoring the line, but the program. The title is thus misleading.

Comment: @riodoro1 Noted and fixed :)

Comment: Do your names have spaces in them?

Comment: It's not skipping the line. Try putting `cout << s << '\n';` after it to see what it read.

Comment: @Barmar It simply skips it and it won't let me enter any input when it really should..

Comment: I don't think so. I think it's reading the input that it got an error from when you tried to do `cin >> score;` and entered something that wasn't a number.

Comment: Most likely this is a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-in-input-with-spaces)(read string with spaces) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)(mixing getline and cin)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that when you use `cin >> score` and enter something that isn't an integer, the error flag on the `cin` stream is set, and future operations fail. You need to clear this error with `cin.clear()` before you read more input.

Your loop for the student names is also wrong. You never check for the "no more" name. You check for "|" as the name, but not until you finish processing the input. As the instructions say, the purpose of using `no more` as the input is so that `cin >> score` will fail because `more` is not a number.

Instead, use `while (cin >> name >> score)` to read both the name and score at once. When you enter an invalid score, this will fail and the loop ends.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> names;
    string name;
    vector <int> scores;
    int score;
    cout << "Please write a player's name and the player's score: \n";
    while (cin >> name >> score) {
        names.push_back(name);
        scores.push_back(score);
        cin.ignore();
    }       
    cin.clear(); // Clear error flag from above
    for (size_t j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) {
        for (size_t p = 0; p < scores.size(); p++) {
            if (names[j] == names[p] && j != p) {
                cout << "Error! You have reiterated the name: " << names[j] << "\n";
                system("pause");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Please insert a name to see it's score:\n";
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (size_t d = 0; d < scores.size(); d++) {
        if (s == names[d]) { 
            cout << names[d] << "'s score is: " << scores[d] << "\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The duplicate name entry is not checked this way. Maybe a boolean function to check each instance of name entered exists in vector or not would be a better way.

Comment: There's a `for` loop that looks for duplicate names.

Comment: Its not checked in the while() loop, which would detect any duplicate entry

Comment: I checked for it in the `for` loop after the `while` loop. See where I print `"Error! You have reiterated the name: "`

Comment: Yes, but it will throw error after all entries are done. The last sentence of question 19 says exit with error message on duplicate name entry. So it means the check should be in the while loop, not in for.

Comment: The instructions are not specific about when the checking happens.

Comment: Right. But the program will show error  for   `cin >> s`, as preceeding that line, there should be  `string s = " ";`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that missing declaration

Answer (score -1):

What happens here is, when you press enter the character '\n' is still in the stream. So you need to flush cin to be able to continue again. To do so use

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

after every call to cin. The `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max` can be use with the header `#include <limits>`

Comment: `operator >>` ingnores white space which `\n` is considered to be.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. Why is the code working with the snippet I provided then?

Comment: Well now after adding these lines it simply won't execute anything when I tell it to. It simply does "\n" instead of executing the code.

Comment: Aren't the default arguments to `cin.ignore()` the same as the ones you gaver?

Comment: The most likely problem is one of the names has a space in it.  That will cause `cin >> score` to fail since there will still be text in the buffer.  That in turn means ever other call to `cin` will fail untill the buffer and error flags are cleared.

Comment: @Barmar `ignore` is `ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() )`

Comment: @ChenHaviv the code works fine on my end. Did you had the `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` directly after the `cin >> name`?