# how to leave space between string in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a;
string b = "hey";
cin >> a;
if (a == b) {
    cout << "hello \n";

}

int z = 40;
string x = "";
string y = "weather";
cin >> x;
if (x == y) {
    cout << "the temp is " << z << endl;
}
return 0;
    }
```

it works correctly but once I change string y to a sentence that have spaces in it it does not work for example :
         string y = "this is a sentence";

Comment: `cin >> x;` will read into `x` until it finds whitespace. Use `getline` to get strings with included whitespace (up to the delimiter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::cin in input with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-in-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Use getline() function or you can also use gets() function.

If you are using STL string then,

```
getline(cin,str);   /*it will work */
```

If you are not using STL string then,

```
#include <cstdio>
char *gets( char *str );
```

Comment: Never use `gets`, **especially** in C++.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: Thanks for answer but sadly I can't do it now I am still learning I haven't learned that yet I just though to create very simple chat bot maybe 5 or 6 sentences with what I learnt but it seems I need to learn more