# String over 8 chars causes infinite loop C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm having a problem with my C++ code and I haven't really found anything online that describes *why* i'm having this problem. Here is my code:

```
/*
Write a program using vectors and iterators that allows a user to main-
tain a list of his or her favorite games. The program should allow the
user to list all game titles, add a game title, and remove a game title.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> gamesList;
    gamesList.reserve(10);
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    string menu = "1. List all games\n";
    menu += "2. Add a game title\n";
    menu += "3. Remove a game title\n";
    menu += "4. Quit\n";
    string newTitle = "", removeTitle = "";
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 4)
    {
        cout << menu;
        cout << "\nYour choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                for (iter = gamesList.begin(); iter != gamesList.end(); ++iter)
                {
                    cout << *iter << endl;
                }
                cout << "\nList capacity is " << gamesList.capacity() << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Please enter a game title :";
                cin >> newTitle;
                gamesList.push_back(newTitle);
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Which game title do you want to remove?\n";
                cin >> removeTitle;
                for (int i = 0; i < gamesList.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if (gamesList[i] == removeTitle)
                    {
                        gamesList.erase(gamesList.begin() + i);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Good bye!";
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the program and enter Pong, Breakout and Tetris to the list, it works fine. If I run the program and enter Half Life or any title longer than 8 characters, the program goes into an infinite loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's the number of characters? Might the problem not be with names containing spaces?

Comment: Your going to need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces) and because of that you will also need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: I understand now. Thank you both. Those links will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the length, it's that you try to enter names with *spaces* in them. The input operator `>>` separates on space. So if you enter `Half Life` as a name, the input operator will only read `Half`.

You probably should use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead, to read the names.

As for the infinite loop, it's because since part of the name is still in the input buffer (with a leading space) then when you attempt to read a number for the menu entry, the input will fail, leave the input in the buffer, and you will not detect it and go into an infinite loop where you want to read an integer, fail and on and on and on...

Using `std::getline` will solve both problems. But if you want to make sure this won't happen again you have to add some error checking when reading the integer for the menu alternative. This can simply be something like

```
while (!(cin >> choice))
{
    // Input of menu alternative failed, ignore input until the end of the line
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

[An `std::istream::ignore` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: Ah OK thank you. I didn't know >> behaved like that.

Comment: @user10001110101 reading (and *understanding*) [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) for functions you use is usually a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should include header `<string>` because there are used declarations from the header in the program.

```
#include <string>
```

This code snippet of removing an element from the vector

```
       case 3:
            cout << "Which game title do you want to remove?\n";
            cin >> removeTitle;
            for (int i = 0; i < gamesList.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (gamesList[i] == removeTitle)
                {
                    gamesList.erase(gamesList.begin() + i);
                }
            }
```

is wrong.

First of all according to the assignment you have to remove only one element. 
To remove an element you can use the just one statement without any loop

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

gamesList.erase( std::find( gamesList.begin(), gamesList.end(), removeTitle ) );
```

As for you problem then the `oprator >>` inputs characters until a white space character is encountered. Instead of the operator you should use function `getline`. Take into account that you will also need to use member function `ignore` to remove a new line character from the input bu=ffer.