# cin std::string with spaces

Tags: c++, string, inputstream, cin

I want to read an `std::string` named `destination` from `std::cin` until a given delimiter. By default, `std::istream::operator<<` interrupts after a space when I do `destination << std::cin`. If `destination` were a `char[]`, I could use `std::getline`.

What do we use for `std::string?`

Comment: code. add some code.

Comment: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Its nut a duplicate @Tas!!!!! I want to cin a std::string not char[] and I have mentioned that!!!!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough when I said _read all the answers_. If you scroll down just a little further beneath the accepted answer, you should find [an answer there that helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5838803/4143855)

Comment: @EduardRostomyan That's why he suggested to read all of the answers. Use `std::getline`. It's not the same as `std::cin::getline`.

Comment: About my edit: did I get your intent correctly?

Comment: ouch, my bad @Tas, ty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your premise is wrong: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does work with `std::string`:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input,
                                           std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                                           CharT delim );
```

This means you can read from `std::cin` to an `std::string` until a given delimiter:

```
std::string destination;
std::getline(std::cin, destination, '|');
```

(`'|'` taken as an exemple delimiter)

---

**Note**: you should check `getline`'s return before reading from `destination`. `getline` returns a reference to `std::cin` which can be converted to a `bool` whose value is `true` if the stream is in a correct state:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, destination, '|') == false) {
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline`, like this:

```
std::string InputWithSpaces;
std::getline (std::cin,InputWithSpaces);
std::cout << InputWithSpaces << std::endl; //test 1 2 3
```