# Why I cant read " ", space, as a character

Tags: c++, string, insert

I'm trying to insert a `string` into another `string`. when I find the first apparition of the user defined character, and inserting the string after the first position of the character and I can't get the program to take `' '`(space) as a character not as a separator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strings.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,ok=0,k=0,p=0;
    char s[256],aux[256],a[256];
    char c;
    cin.get(s,256);//reading the string
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(a,256);//reading the string that I want to insert
    cin.getline();
    cin>>c;//reading the separator
    strcpy(aux,s);
    while(j<=strlen(s) && s[j]!=c)//searching for the first apparition of the separator
    {
        j++;
    }
    ok=strlen(a);
    strcpy(s+j+1,a);//making room for the string that insert and inserting the string
    strcpy(s+j+ok,aux+j);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: What is the input you give your program? What is the expected and actual output? Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger to see the contents of all arrays and variables you have? And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Have you tried debugging this and seeing that what you are trying to insert as a separator is actually inserted? You are executing multiple input functions and it can become confusing. Let's debug this and see what you get, I'm here if you have questions.

Comment: `strings.h` is not a part of C++. It's a POSIX library. Please use `std::string` with `#include <string>` rather than legacy C-style character arrays

Comment: I tried debugging it, and I inserted the <string> libray. The program works just fine with other characters as c variable but it does nothing with " "(space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to include library `"string.h"` in order to compile your program. Then, you can do as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,ok=0,k=0,p=0;
    char s[256],aux[256],a[256];
    char c;
    cin.get(s,256);//reading the string
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(a,256);//reading the string that I want to insert
    c = getchar();//reading the separator
    getchar(); // for getting enter from keybord
    strcpy(aux,s);
    int len = strlen(s); // this function is of time complexity O(len)
    while ( j <= len && s[j]!=c)//searching for the first apparition of the separator
    {
        j++;
    }
    ok=strlen(a);
    strcpy(s+j+1,a);//making room for the string that insert and inserting the string
    strcpy(s+j+1+ok,aux+j);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Note: Instead of calling `strlen(s)` method again and again inside `while loop`, you can simply calculate length of string - `s` once. otherwise, it will increase time complexity.

Comment: I compiled it. Still when I want to use " "(space) as the character I'm looking for it does nothing. I did used "/" and other characters as separators and it worked just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you dont want to use space as a separator character - c. I'm correcting it.

Comment: You may check it now!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally space we take as separator,I think it will also have ASCII value.
please check sample code i am inserting space just like any other character. if i find character 'e', i am inserting space. we also have isspace function to check for space in C++.

```
char str[]="Examplesentence to test isspace\n";
while (str[i])
{
c=str[i];
if (c =='e' )  c=' ';
putchar (c);
}
```