# if statement is not outputting anything C++

Tags: c++

I am Making a Simple game and I am having a problem with the if statement. I have the formatting of the statement right but there is no output

I am trying to output a cout text and then ask the user to input another action

I have tried isolating the Problem by trying to print out the string which I used to record the input for the action

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int charisma1 = 50;
    string action, choice;

    cout << "Hello There!\n";

    cout << "\nBefore we start you need to learn the basics commands of theis game\n";
    cout << "\nGo North -- To Move North\n";
    cout << "Go South -- To Move South\n";
    cout << "Go West -- To Move West\n";
    cout << "Go East-- To Move East\n";

    cout << "\nIF YOU WANT TO SKIP THE TUTORIAL THEN TYPE \"Yes\": ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice != "yes") {
        cout << "\nAttack -- To Attack your enemy (You will have to however have a weapon equiped)\n";
    }

    cout << "\nEast of House\n";

    cout << "\nYou are standing outside in a clearing west of a east house with a boarded front door\n";
    _getch();
    cout << "You see a mailbox there\n";
    cin >> action;
    if (action == "open mailbox"){
        cout << "You see a letter inside\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you see a mailbox
Input: open mailbox
you see a letter inside
Input: read letter
Letter goes here

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Note that `#include <conio.h>` and `_getch();` won't compile with most c++ compilers. You should ditch that stuff for sake of portability.

Comment: You ask to type "Yes" but you check for "yes". Try converting the answer to lower-case and then check it.

Comment: "... by trying to print out the string which I used to record the input for the action" where do you do that? I cannot find it in the code you posted. What did you get as output?

Comment: Also for your input check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces

Comment: @macroland Looks like a dupe for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
cin >> action;
if (action == "open mailbox"){
    cout << "You see a letter inside\n";
}
```

The conditional in the `if` is bound to be `false`. The line to read into `action` will stop reading when it encounters a whitespace character. If you want to read whitespace characters into `action`, you can use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
std::getline(cin, action);
```

However, that will lead to another problem. The previous call to read from `cin`,

```
cin >> choice;
```

is going to leave the newline character in the stream. Before you can use `std::getline`, make sure you read and discard the newline character (and anything else before the newline character). You can use [`cin.ingore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for that.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::getline(cin, action);
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 0):

in C++, cin is whitespace-delimited. That means once the function encounters a space, tab, newline, etc, it stops reading characters in. To read a full line (i.e. delimit on Enter) use the getline() function instead and pass it the destination string.