# Take a space as an input in single char data type?

Tags: c++, char, cin

I just want to take space as an empty place as I am coding an 8-piece puzzle problem. However ‘[space]’ is not being accepted.

Here’s the sample function.

```
void puzzle_8::initial_string_setup()
{
    int i=0;
    string initial="abcdefghi";
    string allowed=" 12345678";
    char to_check;
    bool check=false;
    while(i!=9)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t"<<initial[0]<<"  |  "<<initial[1]<<"  |  "<<initial[2]<<endl<<"\t\t---+-----+---"<<endl<<"\t\t"<<initial[3]<<"  |  "<<initial[4]<<"  |  "<<initial[5]<<endl<<"\t\t---+-----+---"<<endl<<"\t\t"<<initial[6]<<"  |  "<<initial[7]<<"  |  "<<initial[8]<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter input for place "<<initial[i]<<": ";
        cin>>to_check;
        check=false;
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            if (to_check==allowed[j])
            {
                check=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(check==true)
        {
            initial[i]=to_check;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\n\nInvalid entry\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, how can I stop user from entering double digits?

EDIT:

Changing `cin>>to_check` to `to_check=getchar()` lets me take `space` as an input and solves my query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: `how can I stop user from entering double digits?` I don't understand that, a digit is a character `0`, `1`, ....`9`. What is a "double digit"? You mean inputting a digit followed by another digit? Just remember that the lest character entered was a digit, read next character, and check.

Comment: @KamilCuk By double digits, I meant that if user enters lets say 23, it takes it as double input and fills two places. However, I figured that can be avoided by adding an `if` condition in my `for` loop to check if the entry is `>10`.

Comment: It's almost always bettet to use `std::getline` and then you can validate the input on a line-by-line basis. It will include spaces and you can easily check the lenght of the input to make sure it's only one character. `std::stoi` will let you convert the line to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cin` or any `ios` streams can ignore whitespaces (spaces, tabs, newlines) on input depending on the `skipws` flag.

You can disable ignoring whitespaces with [std::noskipws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws):

```
cin >> std::noskipws;
```

Note that then you will have to handle the newlines `'\n'` and whitespaces in your code in input.

Answer (score 1):

A single space is not recognized as a "full" input by the `cin` in your code, because it needs to be finished by an enter. You need to replace it by

`to_check = getchar();`

so, if you type a space it will be saved in your `to_check` variable