# cin.getline : no matching function for call

Tags: c++, string, cin

In many answers and questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces) one, it is recommended to use `cin.getline` from `<string>` and not `getline(cin, variable)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    cin.getline(name);
}
```

But in my case I have build issue:

```
g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:8:21: error: no matching function for call to 
   ‘std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string&)’
    8 |     cin.getline(name);
      |                     ^
```

Comment: Did you mean `std::getline(cin,...)`?

Comment: Why don't just read the manul [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) and be aware of your wrong code?

Comment: @S.M. Because I didn't understand why there are `std::getline` and `std::cin::getline` and they are not the same

Comment: You have asked nothing in your topic.

Comment: The link in your question shows exactly your problem; you need a second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error told by the compiler, it is evident that there is no such function overload that accepts a type *reference to `std::string`* (for `cin.getline()`). Rather, it accepts parameters like:

```
const int MAX = 100;

char input[MAX];
cin.getline(input, MAX);
// Or better
// cin.getline(input, sizeof input);
```

Comment: So there is no OOP method on `cin` to read a string with spaces, one needs `std::getline`

Comment: @nowox the `cin.getline()` also accepts whitespaces. See [live](https://onlinegdb.com/HyG_MsQrw). But `std::getline()` is more convenient to use.