# How can I store 'space' character into a list

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have declared this vector
`vector<char> germat{ SekuencaEfjaleve.begin(), SekuencaEfjaleve.end() };`
where `SekuencaEfjaleve` is a string that i get as an input from the user. The input always contains a space in the middle, so the user inputs something like this **423 fgfh=**, and when I print out the list it stops at 3 it has only 3 elements.
I read it as `cin >> SekuencaEfjaleve;` and i print it as

````
        cout << germat[i];
    }```
````

Comment: How do you read the input? How do you add it to the vector? How do you print it? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please read (or refresh) [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i read it as cin >> SekuencaEfjaleve . I output it as ```for (int i = 0; i <= germat.size() - 1; i++) {
  cout << germat[i];
 }```

Comment: [`std::cin` input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you use `string` rather then using character type `vector`, like this way, it is lot easier to use.

```
string germat;

getline(cin, germat);  // used C++ builtin function `getline()` for taking string input with spaces

// now you can access by `germat[index]`
```

or you can take your `SekuencaEfjaleve` string with `getline()`, like:
`getline(cin, SekuencaEfjaleve)` and now you can access with `SekuencaEfjaleve[index]`.

Comment: well it seems to work this way thank you . But it still does not asnwers the problem i had which makes this question useles