# read two string Lines getline with C++ from User

Tags: c++, string, input, cin

I would like to read 2 strings from terminal, but my code is not working. I have two cout and getline.
My Goal is: Read Two strings with spaces

MyCode:

```
cout << "Description  " << endl;
getline (cin,VarGros);

cout << "Description1:  " << endl;
getline(cin, VarBeschr);
```

If I run this Code, They print

```
Description
Description1  ((User Input))
```

Comment: What input did you enter? Is it possible you used `std::cin >> something;` before the first getline?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question

Comment: my input: here is mr and mrs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Comment: the code dont wait of a input and print Description, you entered, Description1

Comment: I think your issue is something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: @Mr.Conte If the linked duplciate is not accurate then please post a [mre]