# Why does my std::getline invocation not work?

Tags: c++, getline

I'm new here so please excuse if I didn't explain the question well or something. This is my code, and I'm trying to get user input. The thing is I want to print out what the user says even if they include spacing. However, I'm stuck. This is my code... any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char name[200];
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::getline( std::cin, name );
    std::cout << "Welcome to CS adventures, " << name <<"!";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) requires a `std::string`, not a character array.

```
char name[200];
```

should become

```
std::string name;
```

but student programmers seem to have been made to suffer because instructors tend to have a "No `string`s" rule. You may need to use [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) because it will accept a character array. In this case

```
std::getline( std::cin, name );
```

needs to become

```
std::cin.getline( name, sizeof(name) );
```

Comment: [Semi-relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD1KqbDdmuE)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code doesn't compile.
`std::getline` expects an `std::string`, not a `char *`.

The following code works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::getline( std::cin, line );
    std::cout << "Welcome to CS adventures, " << line <<"!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getline` as follows
`std::cin.getline(name,sizeof(name));`
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You should use string type for name variable. "Getline(***string***)" method only works with string parameter. Here's example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    int main ()
    {
      std::string name;
    
      std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
      std::getline (std::cin,name);
      std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    
      return 0;
    }
```