# When turning a char with multiple characters into a string with stringstream, spaces dissapear

Tags: c++

This is the part of a code code:

```cpp
time_t now = time(0);
char* date_and_time = ctime(&now);
cout << date_and_time << endl;
string date_and_time_string;
stringstream ss;
ss << noskipws << date_and_time;
ss >> noskipws >> date_and_time_string;
cout << date_and_time_string << endl;
```

I cant understand how `date_and_time` is a `char` when it has multiple characters, and when I want to get it to a string, it just stops when spaces come. I tried putting it with or without `noskipws` but to no avail. If printing `date_and_time` is something like `"Thu Jul 01 23:52:46 2021"`, when it turns to string it is just `"Thu"`.

Comment: `std::ctime` - __Return value__ - _"Pointer to a static null-terminated character string..."_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime . To get it into a string `std::string date_and_time_string{date_and_time};`

Comment: *"I cant understand how date_and_time is a char"* -- that's good, as `char*` is not `char`.

Comment: First point of clarification, from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), about `noskipws`: *"Has no effect on output."*. That is, you'll see a difference if you look at `ss.str()` instead of `date_and_time_string`. Now your question should become something ("why did the stream extraction stop at a space?") for which we have a duplicate lying around somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cant understand how `date_and_time` is a `char` when it has multiple characters

It is not a single `char`, it is a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`s.

> when I want to get it to a string, it just stops when spaces come.

Because that is how `operator>>` works. It stops reading on whitespace or EOF, whichever occurs first.

> I tried putting it with or without noskipws but to no avail.

`noskipws` before the first `>>` tells it not to skip *leading* whitespace. But your input string does not have any, so the `noskipws` is effectively a no-op in this situation. And it has no effect on the 2nd `>>` because the 1st one clears that flag from the stream after it is done reading.

> If printing `date_and_time` is something like `"Thu Jul 01 23:52:46 2021"`, when it turns to string it is just `"Thu"`.

Because you are using `>>` to parse the string. This is normal behavior.

If you want the whole string, use `std::getline()` instead:

```cpp
stringstream ss;
ss << date_and_time;
/* alternatively:
istringstream ss(date_and_time);
*/
getline(ss, date_and_time_string);
```

Or, since there is really no reason to use `std::(i)stringstream` at all in this situation, you can just assign `date_and_time` as-is directly to `date_and_time_string`:

```cpp
date_and_time_string = date_and_time;
```