# Array of string type

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cin

I have declared a string array of [15]. Actually to store names. I execute it fine, but when I enter the complete name (including space; First name+[space]+last name) the program misbehaves. I cannot find the fault

I have declared multiple string arrays in the program, when I input the name with space it doesn't executes fine. I am using `cin>>` function to input in the array. like

```
string name[15];
int count=0;    cout << "enter your name" << endl;    
cin >> name[count];
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces

Comment: The program behaves exactly as it's supposed to, only your epxectations are wrong. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt The third bullet point for function (2) states that it stops at the first whitespace.

Comment: Also, before changing only *some* of the input to using getline, please consult [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 2):

> I am using `cin>>` function to input in the array.

That is the problem. [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is meant for reading [*formatted input*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction), so it stops reading when it encounters whitespace between tokens. But you want [*unformatted input*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction) instead. To read a string with spaces in it, use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
string name[15];
int count=0;
cout << "enter your name" << endl;    
getline(cin, name[count]);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tLoobx)

Comment: i try doing it.. still the problem

Comment: @MINAAMAHMAD [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/tLoobx). Your problem must be in other code we can't see here. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action.

Comment: it worked by using    getline(cin>>ws,name[count});     i cannot figure out the purpose of "ws".

Comment: @MINAAMAHMAD [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) simply reads and discards whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc) from an input stream.