# Why I can't give input in date here. and also not getting the full output of the name

Tags: c++

I can't get the full output of the name, only the first name is getting printed. And I can't input in Date structure variable that I have created inside the Visitor structure. I am just starting to learn and can't seem to find any problem with it. I ran it on both my system and online C++ compiler.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    /* Made a Structure here to store date. */
    struct Date {
        int day, month, year;
    };



    /* A structure to store visitor details. */

    struct Visitor {
        string name;
        Date visitday;   //Structure variable of Date Structure inside Visitor Structure.
    };

    Visitor person;      // Structure Variable of Visitor Structure.

    cout << "Enter Name-";
    cin >> person.name;
    cout << "\nEnter Day- ";
    cin >> person.visitday.day;
    cout << "\nEnter Month- ";
    cin >> person.visitday.month;
    cout << "\nEnter Year- ";
    cin >> person.visitday.year;
    cout << "\nName- " << person.name << " " << "\nDay of Visit- ";
    cout << person.visitday.day << "/" << person.visitday.month << "/" << person.visitday.year;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: That works well, maybe you forgot to add an newline at the end of the last printed line and your console is unable to flush the buffer?

Comment: @Mohammad Aslam The operator >> enters only on word. To enter several words in an object of the type std::string use function getline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::cin input with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
std::cin >> person.name;
```

The parser parses only one word, i.e. treats the space(s) (`' '`) as a separator.

You can use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
std::getline(cin, person.name);
```

This will fill `person.name` with the complete string you enter, till the first newline.

A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).